# "manufactured to the highest standards" vs. "manufactured to meet the highest standards"

Tags: phrases

Can something be "manufactured to the highest standards" or is it "manufactured to meet the highest standards"? According to Google, both wordings are frequently used. I realize that the latter is perfectly fine, but would prefer the former, simply because it's shorter. Is it also correct?

Comment: The elision (in my view) is a question of the high standards of manufacture, not a question of the actual quality of the conformity of the product thus produced. I assume that, legally, one may claim high quality methods without having to prove high quality product. 'Manufactured (according) to highest standards' just says one tried hard, it does not assert that one was successful.

Comment: Using "to meet" there is an old advertising copywriter trick. It uses a weasel word phrasing to imply the standards are met while literally saying all they did was *try* to meet them.

Comment: They're both equally meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

> manufactured to the highest standards

=

> manufactured to **conform to** the highest standards

=

> manufactured to **meet** the highest standards

The first is the more common and preferred structure (for commercial purposes), the second may be used where pedants may object to elision, as in legal documents.

Comment: Thank you! Not allowed to upvote yet, so breaking the rules to show my appreciation :)

Comment: You've broken no rule -- a comment does the same thing, too. You'll get the privileges soon. Good Luck. Nice to be of help all the same.